# Is there any special way of implementing admob ads?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am trying to add admob ads to my app by whenever i try the ads do not show but when i use the test ads it shows. I have also cheked my admob account it has been approved for displaying ads

I have tried using the admob test ads and it shows perfectly

Here is an example of the banner ad

```
mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I expect it to show my ads but it shows only the test ads whenever I replace my ad unit with the test ad unit.

Comment: You have to wait some hours after creating ads id. But it is recommended that you use test device id with your ad id

Answer (score 0):

***Try to confirm that you have used valid banner ad id, If you still not getting real ad wait sometimes and test in another device. Hope it will work***

```
    -----------:Add custom layout:--------------

    <!--Admob Banner Ad-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlAdViewBannerAdmob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>



    public AdView ad;
    AdRequest adRequest;

    //init Ad
    ad =new AdView(context);
            ad.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            ad.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);

    //Load ad    
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .addTestDevice("14C739553C9657EB85559903949D428B") //add test Ids
                    .build();
    //load ad                
    ad.loadAd(adRequest);

    rlAdViewBannerAdmob.addView(ad); // add loaded ad in customview

//do not forget to add *YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID* in manifest
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```